# Error in c# odbcCommand parameterization

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Executing the below code gives me error. **Column 'Username' cannot be null**
Values are being passed in the variables. But I think the `OdbcCommand` statement is not prepared properly.

```
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand 
    { 
    CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO orders(username,name,email,address,contact_number,html_email)
    VALUES(@username,@name,@email,@address,@contact_number,@html_email)",

    Connection = Con 
    };

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", add);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number", contact);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@html_email", table);

    billid = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: are you sure that username value being passed is not null? try to debug it and see.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Yes, I have already checked it. All values are being passed. I doubt if this approach works with mysql. I use it with MSSqlServer but doubtfull about mysql.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OdbcCommand` does not support named parameter syntax, instead you should use a question mark placeholder:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand 
{ 
CommandText = 
"INSERT INTO orders(username,name,email,address,contact_number,html_email)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",

Connection = Con 
};

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", add);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", contact);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", table);

int affectedRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteScalar()` to execute the *insert* statement.

```
int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You probably want to return the last inserted record Id, that's why you are using `ExecuteScalar`. `OdbcCommand` doesn't support then named parameters, so you need to use the placeholder in the query. So overall you need to change the query to this

```
CommandText = "INSERT INTO orders(username,name,email,address,contact_number,html_email)
               VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

Now you can use the `ExecuteScalar()`

```
billid = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO orders(username,name,email,address,contact_number,html_email)
VALUES(@username,@name,@email,@address,@contact_number,@html_email)",Con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", add);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number", contact);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@html_email", table);

billid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Odbc is designed to work with MySql database too so using MySqlCommand is not necessary. Xint0's answer solved my problem. 
Thanks for your help and I appreciate you took effort looking into it.