# Execute stored procedure with one arg in server side and sql recognizes as two args

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, arguments

I'm currently trying to execute a stored procudure with one argument. The database is SQL Server 2005 and I am calling the stored procudure from C# using an `OdbcCommand` like this:

```
OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand("{call sp_dominioMaquinas(?)}");
oCmd.Connection = new OdbcConnection(Config.Config.GetConnectionStringSqlConnection());

string psTipoExportarAux = "'" + psTipoExportar + "'";

oCmd.Parameters.Clear();
oCmd.Parameters.Add("@psTipoExportar", OdbcType.VarChar);
oCmd.Parameters["@psTipoExportar"].Value = psTipoExportarAux;
```

My problem is that my parameter `psTipoExportar` is a string with a comma (,) in it (ex: `a', 'b`) and so SQL Server recognizes it as two parameters instead of one.

Using a tool to see requests to my database, I can see that my request is being misinterpreted (ex: exec sp_dom '''a'', ''b''') as two arguments when I want it to be processed as one.

If anyone could help out, thank you

I'm following [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310130) and I've checked this questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535994/asp-net-odbc-query-with-parameters) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082930/error-when-adding-parameters-to-stored-procedure-call) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583074/execute-parameterized-sql-storedprocedure-via-odbc).

Comment: have you tries " instead of ' ?

Comment: yes, still the same beahvior

Comment: i've managed to find my solution in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465136/split-sql-parameter-on-comma)